# Making Wordpress author follow button, need missing ingredient

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm trying to make a follow button in wordpress where users can press a button that allows them to follow an author they like. (No, I'm not interested in buddypress)

What I've done so far is use the code from Jon Masterson's Post Like System for WordPress http://hofmannsven.com/2013/laboratory/wordpress-post-like-system/ which pretty much adds a +1 update_post_meta when ever a user likes the post.

The problem I've ran into, is if you go all the way to the bottom you'll see that the like system uses update_post_meta to give a +1 to the count of the post meta, which is exactly what I need for the follow button. The problem is that I can't find a function update_author_meta to store the ++$author_follow_count for that specific author. If you know of a way for me to store and update the follow count for a specific author, or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
function follow_scripts() {
wp_localize_script( 'jk_like_post', 'ajax_var', array(
    'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'ajax-nonce' )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'follow_scripts' );

/**
* (2) Save follow data
*/
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_jk-author-follow', 'jk_author_follow' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_jk-author-follow', 'jk_author_follow' );
function jk_author_follow() {
   $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'ajax-nonce' ) )
        die ( 'Nope!' );

if ( isset( $_POST['jk_author_follow'] ) ) {

    $author_id = $_POST['author_id']; // author id
    $author_follow_count = get_author_meta( $author_id,        "_author_follow_count", true ); // author follow count

    if ( function_exists ( 'wp_cache_post_change' ) ) { // invalidate WP Super Cache if exists
                $GLOBALS["super_cache_enabled"]=1;
                wp_cache_post_change( $post_id );
    }

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { // user is logged in
        $user_id = get_current_user_id(); // current user
        $meta_AUTHORS = get_user_option( "_followed_authors", $user_id ); // author ids from user meta
        $meta_USERS = get_author_meta( $author_id, "_user_followed" ); //user ids from author meta
        $followed_AUTHORS = NULL; // setup array variable
        $followed_USERS = NULL; // setup array variable

        if ( count( $meta_Authors ) !=0 ) { // meta exists, set up values
            $followed_AUTHORS = $meta_AUTHORS;
        }

        if ( !is_array( $followed_AUTHORS ) )  // make array just in case
            $followed_AUTHORS = array();

        if ( count( $meta_USERS ) !=0 ) { // meta exists, set up values
            $followed_USERS = $meta_USERS[0];
        }

        if ( !is_array( $followed_USERS ) ) //make an array just in case
            $followed_USERS = array();

        $followed_AUTHORS['author-'.$author_id, "_user_followed"] = $author_id; // Add author id to user meta array
        $followed_USERS['user-'.$user_id] = $user_id; // add user id to author meta array
        $user_follows = count( $followed_AUTHORS ); // count user follows

 // *** Where the snag is ****
        if ( !AlreadyFollowed( $author_id ) ) { // follow the author
            update_post_meta( $author_id, "_user_followed", $followed_USERS ); // Add user ID to author meta
            update_post_meta( $author_id, "_author_follow_count", ++$author_follow_count ); // +1 count author meta
            update_user_option( $user_id, "_followed_authors", $followed_Authors ); // Add author ID to user meta
            update_user_option( $author_id, "_author_follow_count", $user_follows ); // +1 count user meta
            echo $author_follow_count; // update count on front end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posts have custom meta information as a feature and therefore you can add custom meta values. Author, as far as I know doesn't have a custom meta information.

You could create a new table, and write custom update_author_meta function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, would implementing a function like that be as easy as CREATE TABLE update_author_meta? Or is it a lot more complicated?

Comment: Yup as easy as that. You would create a table and write a function to add a value every time it is called. Also use the wpdb object http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb to do this, it removes lot of boiler plate code.

Comment: Would something like this work? `$wpdb->update( $wpdb->update_author_meta, array($author_id, "meta_key" => "_author_follow_count", "meta_value" => ++$post_like_count ), array("%d", %s", "%d"));`

Comment: Or would I use insert instead? `$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->update_author_meta, array($author_id, "meta_key" => "_author_follow_count", "meta_value" => ++$author_follow_count ), array("%d", %s", "%d"));`

Comment: The accepted answer here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145007/wpdb-insert-or-if-exists-update looks a lot better. You'd have to check whether the row exists or not first and then decide to insert or update otherwise.